# How to run the following Google Apps Script function whenever new data is entered to Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, google-forms

I am making automation which automatically fills google form when a new data is added to the Google sheet and have written following apps script function for automation

```
  function myFunction() {
  var formUrl = "url";

  var wrkBk = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var wrkSht = wrkBk.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


            // loop ?
          
  var name = wrkSht.getRange("A").getValue();
  var email = wrkSht.getRange("B").getValue();
  var institute = wrkSht.getRange("C").getValue();
  var qualification = wrkSht.getRange("D").getValue();
  var linkedin = wrkSht.getRange("E").getValue();
  var source = wrkSht.getRange("F").getValue();
  var additional= wrkSht.getRange("G").getValue();
  var track= wrkSht.getRange("H").getValue();
  
     var datamap =   {  
       "entry.1870580307": name,
        "emailAddress"    : email ,
        "entry.172794055"    : institute,
        "entry.2041507911"    : qualification ,
        "entry.981764969"   : linkedin,
        "entry.1599200340"   : source ,
        "entry.835533968"   : additional,
        "entry.652935633"   : track
      };

      var options ={
        "method" : "post",
        "payload" : datamap
      };


      UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl, options);



}
```

How can I run this script whenever there is new entry in the spreadsheet?
The data in the spreadsheet is extracted from my webpage and will be stored in the spreadsheet using google API.

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help, please add more details like the briefly describing how the data will be entered (a user will manually enter the data cell by cell, they will do copy/pasting, will be using a formula like IMPORTRANGE, ...) and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var formUrl = "url";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach(r => {
    var datamap = {
      "entry.1870580307": r[0],
      "emailAddress": r[1],
      "entry.172794055": r[2],
      "entry.2041507911": r[3],
      "entry.981764969": r[4],
      "entry.1599200340": r[5],
      "entry.835533968": r[6],
      "entry.652935633": r[7]
    };
    var options = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": datamap
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl, options);
  });
}
```

function onAnyEdit() {
myfunction();
}

Comment: I tried this code sir but it returns following error:
 
```Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en" class="HB1eCd-UMrnmb"><head><link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="16x16" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/spreadsheets/... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: I just showed you how to build the loop the rest is your code.